# How to use numeric value in WHERE clause using dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, where-clause

I use a dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @p_Prefix
SET @p_Prefix = 'SIN'

DECLARE @p_DetId bigint
SET @p_DetId = 1243

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM cds' + @p_Prefix + 'Det WHERE sindetid = '+ @p_DetId;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 23
> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

If I convert `@p_DetId` from `bigint` to `varchar`, then the query runs perfectly. Is there any way to use `bigint` in the `where` clause?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: You're supposed to parametrize your query, not concatenate values directly. Read about sp_executesql

Comment: In addition, read up on data type precedence, `cast/convert` and `concat`

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is that `bigint` has a higher precedence than a string, so it's trying to convert the string to `bigint`.

But in any case you need to parameterize your query properly, rather than concatenating.

```sql
DECLARE @p_Prefix nvarchar(100) = N'SIN';
DECLARE @p_DetId bigint = 1243

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
FROM ' + QUOTENAME('cds' + @p_Prefix + 'Det') + '
WHERE sindetid = @p_DetId;
';

exec sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@p_DetId bigint',
   @p_DetId = @p_DetId;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Will this work in UPDATE query too?